# message box effecting my program

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am making a game for windows 8 as metro application. When I execute the following code without showing message box it is not at all responding. when i show message box the entire code works fine. What is the problem? Can any one help me?

```
public async void move()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i = 0;

        while (i<5)
        {
            Anim.Begin();
            int n = rand.Next(97, 123);
            char ch = (char)n;

            textBlock10.Text =textBlock9.Text;

            textBlock9.Text = textBlock8.Text;
            textBlock8.Text = textBlock7.Text;
            textBlock7.Text = textBlock6.Text;
            textBlock6.Text = textBlock5.Text;
            textBlock5.Text = textBlock4.Text;
            textBlock4.Text = textBlock3.Text;
            textBlock3.Text = textBlock2.Text;
            textBlock2.Text = textBlock1.Text;
            textBlock1.Text = textBlock.Text;
            textBlock.Text = ch.ToString();

            /*MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("test");
            msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("ÿes", null, "YES"));
            msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("no", null, "NO"));
            var op = await msg.ShowAsync();//Showing the message
            if ((string)op.Id == "YES")
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), null);
            */System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(50);
            Anim.Stop();
        }
    }
```

the above function is used to move data from one point to another point on screen using text blocks. Anim is storyboard that moves these text blocks to their next places. Please help me

Comment: The first issue is that your method signature is `void`. In general you should only use `async void` for event handlers (button click for example). All `async` methods under the event handler should use `Task`.  Your signature should look like: `public async Task move()`

Answer (score 1):

Put "await" in front of Task.Delay(50);

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(50);
```

Otherwise you implement an infinite loop and the app is not responsive because you are burning your CPU :-)